# ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: No route to host

Tags: django, heroku

Hi I in an attempt to connect to more than one heroku account I did a number of stuff that has led to this error. "ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: No route to host" I dont know what the problem is or how to solve it so I want to start all over with heroku and ssh keys on my machine. How to I delete the present configurations and start afresh?

Answer (score 1):

A few things I would attempt to do:

1. Ensure that there is no quirky setup in your HOSTS (/etc/hosts) file that is causing confusion
2. Check your ~/.ssh directory and ensure that the keys you expect to be there ... are there.
3. Check your ~/.ssh/config file for any incorrect information
4. Ensure that your heroku SSH server is actually listening on port 22. A lot of people will change the default SSH port for security purposes.
5. Ensure that the private key that you're attempting to use is uploaded to the heroku server. Some SSH instances won't tell you that it's an invalid key for security purposes. Instead it will just give you the rejection message you mentioned.

If I think of any other diagnostics I'll be sure to update.

Best of luck.

Comment: Is there no way to start all over? Am finding it difficult to follow as am very new at this. What key am I to check out for . in my .ssh folder there are three files i

Comment: Your .pub (public) key is the key that you should put on other servers. Your private key should be held on to by you and you only. You can certainly start all over by deleting all your keys and generating a new one to put on your Heroku server. Just make sure you have a way to connect to your heroku server without a key before you delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something is set oddly in your $HOME/.ssh/config file. You can try backing up this file and then removing it to see if it resolves your problem.

Comment: No it did not. Isnt there a way to start all over?